# Pass parameter in v-bind:href

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I have a `<a>` tag in my vue component & by checking some condition `v-bind:href` may differ. I have used ternary operator for it and in the else part I want to pass id with the url, but with not as part of url (like '/test/' +id). id should not be in the url. so how to do it?

This is how I tried for it & it giving me the compile error due to comma before id in else part,

```
<a v-bind:href="type === 'single' ? '/user/'+user.id+'/edit' : '/profile',user.id">
```

- Url should be like "/profile"

Comment: Could you please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/68630029/edit) to provide examples of what the various URLs should look like? Also, did you mean to use `'/profile/' + user.id` in the _else_ part?

Comment: No I want to use else part url as "/profile" & I want to pass user id with it.but not with url.

Comment: _"I want to pass user id with it.but not with url"_... how exactly do you imagine that working?

Comment: In laravel php I have achieved it as follows, route('my.profile',['user_id'=>$user->id])

Comment: I don't really know Laravel very well but my limited knowledge says that it will include the user ID in the generated URL wherever you have defined the `user_id` parameter in the route URL

Comment: I have done it as follows, "'/profile?user_id='+user.id". Thank you @Phil.

Comment: So you want `user_id` as a query parameter? If you'd said that at the start and provided actual examples of the URL you wanted (ie `/profile?user_id=1`), you could have solved this half an hour ago

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have resolved it as follows,

```
<a v-bind:href="type === 'single' ? '/user/'+user.id+'/edit' : '/profile?user_id='+user.id">
```